# Dragging anchors with jQuery : IE not updating cursor

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, cursor, draggable

Ever noticed that if you make an anchor () draggable using jQuery and you set to have a certain cursor to be displayed, IE keeps the pointer displayed regardless of your selection. See the sample code below:

`$("a, div").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move"
});`

It seems like IE keeps the cursor style as at the time of the 'mousedown', until the button is released. All other browsers honor the cursor style.

Anybody have an idea how to ensure the cursor style while dragging anchors?

Comment: I can't even get FF to honor the cursor option on an anchor: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/dWs2m/1/

Comment: I managed it using css. Using the ui-draggable-dragging class. My issue was just with IE

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `<body>` a cursor untill mouseup? i know i might be a lame solution. But it could work...

Comment: I did, but I seems to keep the cursor as it was at mousedown. I noticed that if an error occurs, focus is removed from the anchor and the cursor displays as intended. I am using an icon on my draggable to provide the functionality I needed. But solution to this might help plenty other devs...

Comment: Sometimes using `event.preventDefault()` on the mousemove event works. But I'm not sure. You could try it on all the events - up/down/move